# Can the "converse" of a quantifier statement be equivalent to the original one?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm confused about this question:

> Let A, B, and C be subsets of some universal set S.
> Consider the implication:
> $x \in A \land x\in B \Rightarrow x \in C$
> Which of the following statements are equivalent to the negation of this implication?
> (a)$\exists x\in$$C^c$ such that x$\in A\cap B$.
> (b)∃x$\in$A∪B such that x$\notin$C.
> (c)∃x$\in$C such that x$\notin$A∩B.
> (d)∀x$\in$A∩B,x$\notin$C.
> (e)A∩B∩$C^c$$\neq \emptyset$

So what I did was to negate the original implication:
$\lnot(x \in A \land x\in B \Rightarrow x \in C)$
$=\lnot (x\in A\cap B \Rightarrow x \in C)$
$= x\in A\cap B \land x\notin C $
$= x\in A\cap B\cap C^c$  $\Rightarrow A\cap B\cap C^c \neq \emptyset$
So this matches the option (e)
Also, I know that the implication can be expressed as $\forall x \in A\cap B,x\in C$, and by negating this, I get:
$\lnot(\forall x \in A\cap B,x\in C)$
$= \exists x\in A\cap B$ such that $x\notin C$
$= \exists x\in A\cap B$ such that $x\in C^c$
But I think there is no option to match this. Option (a) is like a "converse" of "$ \exists x\in A\cap B$ such that $x\in C^c$". Are these two the same? (Are they equivalent?)
By the way, the answer that the instructor gave was (a) and (e). I am so confused. Can someone help me with this, please?
Thank you!

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE! Please consider using MathJax to write mathematical notations, symbols and equations. This helps in increasing readability of the post. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial!

Comment: (e) is correct and your argument that shows it is correct. (a) is clearly wrong: if $x \in A^c$, then $x \notin A$ and thus $x \notin A \cap B$. Maybe a typo for $x \in C^c$ ...

Comment: If you use the quantifier, you have $\forall x (x \in A \land x \in B \to x \in C)$ and thus, negating it (as you correctly write) we get: $\exists x (x \in A \land x \in B \land x \notin C)$. And this is exactly (e): $A \cap B \cap C^c \ne \emptyset$.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA, oh, I am sorry I made a mistake there in typing the question part. And it should be $C^c$, not $A^c$.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA, that's exactly what I thought! But our instructor said that option (a) is also correct. So I was wondering if the following two expressions are equivalent: $ \exists x\in A\cap B$ such that $x\in C^c$ and $ \exists x\in C^c$ such that $ \exists x\in A\cap B$

Comment: But in general, the [Converse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_(logic)) of $P \to Q$ is $Q \to P$ and the two are **not** equivalent: if it is a Man, then it is Mortal vs if it is Mortal, then it is a Man.

Comment: I am aware of this when it comes to implications. And I am just confused about these quantifier statements.